# Configure logstash output to splunk universal forwarder

Tags: docker, logstash, splunk, logstash-configuration

I'm currently using the elk stack with docker to gather syslogs and was interested inputting the filtered logstash output into splunk universal forwarder to view the data in splunk. Currently I have the splunk universal forwarder installed on the host where the elk docker sits at.

I was wondering what suggestions are there for configuring the logstash output into the splunk universal forwarder?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to go through Docker volume; With volume you can mount the host directory to the Docker container('s); For example; One Docker container can create a log, and other Docker container can process that log.